# Was the attack in Peacemaker a retaliation or simply an attempt to silence Devoe?

Tags: character, the-peacemaker

In the 1997 film "The Peacemaker", LTC Tom Devoe of Army Special Ops is teamed up with the temporary head of the DOE nuclear response unit, Dr. Julia Kelly. Their mission is to track down nuclear warheads that were stolen from a train in Russia.

Russian colonel Dimitri Vertikoff - a friend of Devoe's - helps them track the warheads to a trucking company in Austria that is actually a front for the Russian mafia. To get the information they need, Devoe interrogates the executive in charge of scheduling, but not before the company's security team identifies Devoe as Army Special Ops.

Shortly after leaving the location, they are stopped by several men in two cars and

> Dimitri is gunned down before Devoe can kill the men.

Devoe does not understand the motive behind this and later laments that there was no reason for it.

**Was the attack a retaliation against Devoe for his treatment of the executive, or was it simply an attempt to silence Devoe & Kelly given that they know the truth about the company?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's a combination of everything but mainly stopping the information from getting out.**

Tom says:

> You don't...kill a Dimitri Vertikoff. There are certain rules. Killing him isn't useful.

But if you don't care about the rules, then anyone is "fair game".

Dimitri thought he could bribe his way out but, not realising that the rules are now changed, he went to his death instead.

The company, Kordech, has, it is revealed always been a Mafia/ex-KGB operation but Dimitri implies that Kodoroff has taken control of the company.

> **Julia:**  We've monitored Kordech for years, but it's always been a Mafia/ex-KGB operation.
>
> **Dimitri:** *Till recently*. You must see it in the context of my country. Kodoroff's generation of officers grew up in a crumbling system. [...] Kodoroff and his friends made sure that it never applied to them. But now, even that system is crumbling. **This was Kodoroff's way out, his big score**.

Essentially, the operation has now been taken over by Kodoroff and the **old rules no longer apply**. Kodoroff has an exit strategy and is content to burn any bridge and break any 'rule' to get his money and escape.

Comment: Ah, ok - I took that line about Kodoroff's big score to mean stealing the nukes.